# Deploying desktop application on android using Qt?

Tags: android, qt, qml, qt-quick

**Hello everyone**,
I’ve built a Qt **quick 2 UI project**, then I built a Qt **quick 2 application(from existing QML files)** and chose the main .qml file of my Qt quick 2 UI application as the existing qml file for the Qt quick 2 application, the application runs perfectly for desktop, but when I change the project setting to make it run on android device (Galaxy SIII) it shows only a white page on my S III. 
Note, I’ve run a hello world Qt quick 2 application on my S III and it runs perfectly, I’ve also run several examples from those provided with Qt and they also run perfectly.
By the way: the emulator doesn’t work for me, whenever I start the emulator the Qt is not responding till I close the emulator.

-My system is Windows 8 with visual studio 2010, Qt 5.1(32bit), Qt creator 2.7.2

Any help please !! 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, I suggest that you go for a mixed C++/QML app, and use Qt 5.2 RC1 final (from this week). That way it should produce (at least debug)  apk-s and deploy them to an emulator or actual device just fine (earlier versions had a problem with signing the release apk-s from within Creator, not sure if they fixed it, as I switched to cmdline).

Comment: "White screen" sounds like the assets (QML files, in particular) are not found. Any messages on the console?